# traversing table in dfa to calculate dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table `datecalculation`

it has the following columns

```
| tonode | fromnode | days  |
|---------------------------| 
|  1     |    12    |   80  |
|  3     |    5     |   45  |
|  4     |    6     |   54  |
...
```

the tonode is the result and the fromnode gives you the result by adding the amount of days to the fromnode

The only date that I have is a created date form another table that in this case will be from node now.

Example (first row of 'datecalculation' table)

```
select createddate from nodes 

createddate = 01/01/2013

createddate = fromnode 12 

fromNode 12 + 80 days = 22/03/2013
```

toNode 1 now has this value and we in the datecalculation table where fromNode is id is 1 and use that to calculate the correlating toNode.

Example

Is there a way of traversing this table to get the results in a depth first algortihm manner?

Is this possible in `tsql`?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please fix the explanation.  Statements such as "adding the amount of days to the frommnode" do not mean anything to me.  Provide an example of all the input data and of the results that you want.

Comment: It looks like you might use either a `CROSS APPLY`, or really, something as simple as an `inner join`.  What does your NODES table look like?  Are you trying to insert this data back into some other table?  Or the same table?  Or are you just trying to select it out?  I'm very confused by your example, you seem to be setting `createddate` three times.